# If I define a protocol in a base UIViewController will its children be able to conform to it in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have:

`UITableViewControllerA` (Lists different ways to refine database product results)

`UIViewControllerB` (Controller associated with one of the rows from list above)

BaseController (Subclass of `UIViewController`, contains common code for controllers associated with rows in `UITableViewControllerA` and is their super class)

I can pass data to `UIViewControllerB` from `UITableViewControllerA` easily using the perpareForSegue method. I am now trying to pass data from `UIViewControllerB` to `UITableViewControllerA` when popViewControllerAnimated is called in my `UIButton` custom method that a user taps once they have made a selection of what to refine database product results with.

I decided to use delegation. `UIViewControllerB` which is subclass of a BaseController and in `UITableViewControllerA` I mentioned above that I have a list of ways to refine products:

***Gender*** - ***Size*** - ***Colour*** - ***Price*** - ***Type***

**Rather than define my protocol below in each of their controllers I decided to define it in the BaseController like so:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol BaseViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didTapDoneButtonWithSelection:(NSString *)selection; // use string for now to test

@end

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <BaseViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (UIButton *)clearButton;
- (UIButton *)doneButton;


@end
```

**Then I went over to UIViewControllerB and accessed the delegate property and passed in the string to be sent over to UITableViewControllerA when done button is tapped:**

```
- (void)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"DONE BUTTON TAPPED");
    [[self delegate] didTapDoneButtonWithSelection:@"THIS IS A TEST"];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**In UITableViewControllerA I conform to the delegate protocol:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BaseController.h"

@interface UITableViewControllerA : UITableViewController <BaseViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**In UITableViewControllerA's implementation file I declare an instance var to hold the data passed over from the UIViewControllerB and display in a log message in viewWIllAppear. The didTapDoneButtonWithSelection method gets the data from the argument and stores it in the _test var:**

```
@interface UITableViewControllerA ()

@end

@implementation UITableViewControllerA
{
    NSString *_test;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@", _test);
}

- (void)didTapDoneButtonWithSelection:(NSString *)selection
{
    _test = selection;
}
```

**Issue:**

My log message is giving me (null).

Is what I'm doing possible? or am I going about it the wrong way. If so please correct me with a code example.

Thanks for your time

Regards

Comment: log in `didTapDoneButtonWithSelection`

Comment: Nothing happens. No log at all.

Comment: did you set the delegate instance?

Comment: @MatthewClark all I done was what is shown above. I think that's what I've missed. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I had to grab an instance of UIViewControllerB and set UITableViewControllerA as it's delegate in the prepareForSegue method:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    UITableViewControllerA *tvca = [segue destinationViewController];
    [tvca setDelegate:self];
}
```

However this feels odd, like there is another way I should be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:I think initially misunderstood the question.

If you are using segues the correct answer is the other one. If you aren't then it's:

In UITableViewControllerA when you are about to push the BaseViewController it should look something like this:

```
BaseViewController* base = [[BaseViewController alloc] init];
base.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:base animated:YES];
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Didn't think it would be this difficult passing data back to a previous controller.